# Area under curve equals product of arc length and its projection

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, area

Find equation of a curve whose  area under it equals product of arc length  $L$ and its projection $(b-a)$ on the x-axis.

$$ A = L (b-a)$$

I was trying to establish a corollary to the [Amazing Catenary property](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2361748/an-amazing-property-of-the-catenary/3853554?noredirect=1#comment8065957_3853554)

[image]

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Maybe this can be useful https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2361748/an-amazing-property-of-the-catenary

Comment: A precision to be given... Are $a,b$ fixed or do you want the equation to be valid for any $a,b$? Depending on your response, the answer to the question is different as you can see below.

Comment: Any real numbers $(a,b) \text{ like for example}  \;(1,2) $

Comment: @ David G Stork : Was trying to generalize result of the cited link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Catenary satisfies the given problem

Consider $f(x)=\cosh x+k$. We have
$$A=\int_a^b (k+\cosh x) \, dx=k (b-a)+\sinh b-\sinh a$$
and
$$(b-a)L=(b-a) \int_a^b \sqrt{1+\sinh ^2 x} \, dx=(b-a) \int_a^b \cosh x \, dx=(b-a) (\sinh b-\sinh a)$$
therefore for $k= \frac{(b-a-1) (\sinh b-\sinh a)}{b-a}$ we have $A=(b-a)L$.

we get the result $$f(x)=\cosh x+\frac{(b-a-1) (\sinh b-\sinh a)}{b-a}$$

Comment: I have verified your result numerically. So can we now view your verification as a corollary to the link of your question? Can we also further incorporate $ c \cosh (x/c)?$

Comment: @Narasimham Yes, I think so

Answer (score 0):

Shift the function such that $ a \to 0$

$$ \int_0^x f(t) dt =x  \int_0^x \sqrt{ 1 + (f'(t))^2} dt $$

d.w.r.t.x

$$ f(x) =  \sqrt{ 1 + (f'(x))^2} + \frac{xf''(x)}{\sqrt{ 1 + f'(x)^2} }$$

Sub: $ f(x) \to y$

$$  y = \sqrt{1 + (y')^2} + \frac{ x y''}{ \sqrt{ 1 + y'^2} }$$

Now all you have to do is solve this DE.

Comment: A constant map is an obvious solution. Need to see if there exists an independent second one and look at a uniqueness theorem.

Comment: @Buraian: Thanks.  should n`t the DE dimension also tally? –

Answer (score 0):

**A constant map satisfies the equation. Let's prove that there is no other solution.**

Suppose that $f$ is continuously differentiable. As mentioned, if $f$ is a solution (with adequate translation) it satisfies the functional equation:

$$ \int_0^x f(t) dt =x  \int_0^x \sqrt{ 1 + (f^ \prime(t))^2} dt \tag{1}.$$

The RHS, namely

$$R(x)= x  \int_0^x \sqrt{ 1 + (f^ \prime(t))^2} dt$$ remains invariant if we change $f$ into $g(x) = f(0)  - \int_0^x f^\prime(t) \ dt$ as $g^\prime(x) = - f^\prime(x)$.

However if for a point $x_0$, we have $f^ \prime(x_0) \neq 0$, the LHS of the equation $(1)$ will change locally around $x_0$ if $f$ is replaced with $g$. A contradiction. As this is independent of $x_0$, we get $f^\prime(x) = 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$ meaning that $f$ has to be constant.