# How to solve for the function $f(x)$ such that the area underneath is always equal to the arclength?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, arc-length

First, I set up my equation. The area is obviously $\int f(x) \space dx$. The arclength is $\int \sqrt{1+(\frac{dy}{dx})^2}  \space dx$. Thus, I have the equation $\int f(x) \space dx = \int \sqrt{1+(\frac{dy}{dx})^2}  \space dx$. Now I differentiatie both sides to get $f(x) = \sqrt{1+(\frac{dy}{dx})^2} $. I will now make some substitutions to make it look simpler like this. $y = \sqrt{1 +y'^2}$. This becomes $y^2 = 1+y'^2$. Since we have a function that is similar to its own derivative, I will guess the solution looks like $y = Ae^{kx}$. $y' = Ake^{kx}$. Pugging these values into our equation, I get $(Ae^{kx})^2 = (Ake^{kx})^2 + 1$ or  $A^2e^{2kx} = A^2k^2e^{2kx} + 1$. I am now stuck here, please help.

Comment: How? ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: oh sorry I see my mistake

Comment: Fixed it, thanks GEdagar

Comment: Sorry for all the edits guys, but I have it fixed now

Comment: See my question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2361748/an-amazing-property-of-the-catenary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you got to
$$
y=\sqrt{1+y'^2}\implies 1=y^2-y'^2
$$
This is the equation for a hyperbola, so use hyperbolic coordinates $y=\cosh(u(t))$, $y'=\sinh(u(t))$. The derivative of the first equation combined with the second then implies for $y'\ne0$ that $u'(t)=1$, so $y(t)=\cosh(t+C)$.

The other case $y'(t)=\sinh(u(t))=0$ gives $y=1$, which is also a solution.

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The equation you get is going to be
$$y' = \sqrt{1+y^2}$$
which is nonlinear, but separable. Integrating, you get
$$x = \int \frac{dy}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}$$
and you can solve this with the substitution $y = \sinh (x + C)$.

Comment: does that mean y = sinh(x+C) is the solution

Comment: @SomeGuy You should check whether it actually satisfies the condition you mentioned.

Comment: It doesn't, I just don't understand David's answer

Comment: Slightly wrong.  The equation you get is $y=\sqrt{1+(y')^2}$ or $y'=\sqrt{y^2-1}$.  Then you get  $y=\cosh(x+C)$ as a solution.